# Cannot read function written in baseform

Tags: c#, call

I have a program (aspx page) which inherits the baseform.
My baseform has a function which validates a session.
But currently, the program runs to the page and it didnt go through the baseform and read the function.
I dont know where i go wrong. no error pop out.
I build the page, still no error.

Below is the code which i call the baseform.

```
public partial class TAView : BaseForm
    {
        protected override void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                base.Page_Load(sender,e);
                binddropdownlists();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it because

```
Page.IsPostBack == true
```

?

You can use a debugger, place it at

```
if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
```

And step from there.